# Java Pass by Reference constructor

Tags: java

I created two objects for the test class where I passed the values `10 and 20` and when I passed second object to the test constructor. It returned me `0 0` instead of `40, 4` as an output. Can anyone explain me why is it happening so?

```
class Test{
        public int a,b;
        Test(){
                a=-1;
                b=-1;
        }
        Test(int i,int j){
                a=i;
                b=j;
        }
        void mest(Test o){
                o.a*=2;
                o.b=2*2;
        }
        Test(Test ob){
                ob.a*=2;
                ob.b=2*2;
        }
}
public class Main{
        public static void main(String[] args){
                Test t = new Test(10,20);
                System.out.println(t.a +" "+ t.b);// 10, 20
                t.mest(t);      
                System.out.println(t.a +" "+ t.b);// 20, 4
                Test t2 = new Test(t);
                System.out.println(t2.a +" "+ t2.b); // 0 , 0
        }
}
```

Comment: [You can't pass by reference in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value). You're passing an object reference by value, which isn't the same.

Comment: I don't understand why you expect the results to be anything else. Can you explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Test(Test ob)` constructor mutates the instance variables of the instance you pass to it (`Test ob`), leaving the properties of the newly created instance with default `0` values.

Perhaps you intended to write:

```
Test(Test ob) {
    this.a = ob.a*2;
    this.b = 2*2;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You change the variables of `ob` instead of assigning them to `this.a` and `this.b`.
You probably want to use this:

```
Test(Test ob){
        this.a = ob.a*2;
        this.b = 4;
}
```

You are seeing 0's because the default value of primitive data types is either `0` or `false` in the case of `boolean`.

Edit: In any case you shouldn't alter any variables in a copy constructor except for just copying.